# Отделить дату времени

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо разделить колонку `dt_send_daytime`,  как дд/чч/мм/сс,   где дд - день

Пробовал вот так

```
 string dt_str = row["shedule_dt_send_daytime"].ToString();

 string[] dt_str_tmp = dt_str.Split(':');

 switch (row["time_name_ru"].ToString()) {
   case "Час":
     Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[2] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[3]); //мм:сс
     break;

   case "Неделя":
     Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[0] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[1]); //дд:чч
     break;

   case "День":
     Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[1] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[2]); //чч:мм
     break;

   case " минут":
     Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[3]); //сс
     break; 
 }
```

А если в колонке `name_ru` будет ещё `час`. Как это сделать?
Дополните мой код пожалуйста или другой пример может)

Comment: что значит `будет ещё час` не совсем понятно. Лучше приведите пример как было, и как должно получиться.

Comment: если `Час` будет начинаться с маленькой `час`, `Неделя` будет с маленькой `неделя`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что-бы проверить совпадают ли строковые переменные можно пойти двумя путями:

1. **ToUpper(), ToLower()**
В первом способе нужно взять нашу переменную и перевести все символы в один регистр и сравнивать со значением в том же регистре.
Метод [String.ToUpper()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ewdd6aed(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает копию строки в верхний регистр, т.е. `"Привет"` будет `"ПРИВЕТ"`.
Метод [String.ToLower()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает копию строки в нижнем регистре, т.е. `"Привет"` будет `"привет"`

В вашем случае это:

```
switch (row["time_name_ru"].ToString().ToUpper()) {
   case "ЧАС": ...
```

2. **String.CompareTo()**

Метод [String.CompareTo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx) сравнивает два указанных объекта String (с учетом или без учета регистра) и возвращает целое число, которое показывает их относительное положение в порядке сортировки.

В вашем случае придётся отказаться от `switch` в пользу `if`:

```
string timeNameRu = row["time_name_ru"].ToString().ToUpper();
if (timeNameRu.CompareTo("ЧАС")==0)
{ ... }
```

**UPDATE:**

> а если там будет "часы" или "часов" ?

Метод [String.Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает значение, указывающее, содержит ли указанная строка значение подстроки переданной в качестве параметра

```
string timeName = row["time_name_ru"].ToString().ToUpper();
if (timeNameRu.Contains("ЧАС") == 0)
{ ... }
```

Comment: а если там будет `часы` или `часов`

Comment: Нужно взять дату из колонки `dt_send_daytime`. Т.е `1:1:4:0` каждую неделю,каждый понедельник, в час, 4 минут так должно работать. Можно так сделать?